# Need an better algorithm for complex division

Tags: c#, algorithm, complex-numbers

I am converting Fortran to C# and I have implemented my own Complex struct using doubles. In the Fortran I have a complex calculation

```
c = a/b
a = (-6.756993318630313D-178,2.237434940548793D-178)    COMPLEX(8)
b = (1.381489403189045D-175,-3.000542776128005D-175)    COMPLEX(8)
c = (-1.470726933303390D-003,-1.574781630470373D-003)   COMPLEX(8)
```

My simplistic C# implementation gives `NaN` when I try to do this calculation.

```
public static Complex operator /(Complex complex1, Complex complex2)
{
    var denominator = complex2.Real * complex2.Real + complex2.Imaginary * complex2.Imaginary;
    return new Complex((complex1.Real * complex2.Real + complex1.Imaginary * complex2.Imaginary) / denominator,
            (-complex1.Real * complex2.Imaginary + complex2.Real * complex1.Imaginary) / denominator);
}
```

Considering the algorithm, getting `NaN` is not surprising. The guys who wrote the Intel Fortran compiler are clearly more clever that I am. Can anyone provide an algorithm that will be as good as that used in Fortran?

Comment: If I were dividing 3.5E150 by 1.75E149 on paper or in my head, I would probably cut out E149 from numerator and denominator. So my division would be computed by returning 3.5E1 divided by 1.75E0. It might help avoid overflows if you first check if the numerator and denominator exponents have the same sign, and if so, reduce the exponents by the smaller amount (in absolute value) Then proceed with your code as-is. I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it's possible.

Comment: Do you have to write your own implementation? The [`System.Numerics.Complex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.111).aspx) implementation works fine (i.e. will produce the result you expect/want). You certainly can change the implementation to avoid over/underflow, but I don't see a reason to here. If there is one, you should explain it better.

Comment: If you _do_ have to write your own implementation, I recommend copying an existing algorithm. You could just use the same "Smith's formula" that the built-in `Complex` type uses (see link above). Here are some other alternative approaches: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1608/1608.07596.pdf, or convert to polar and do the math in that domain, then convert back (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_complex_numbers)

Comment: I checked System.Numerics.Complex and it does indeed give the correct answer, agreeing with Fortran to 14 or 15 digits. I can use it for now, but a year ago  I could not access System.Numerics when trying to build an iOS app with Xamarin, so I started using my own Complex struct. I intend to eventually do numerical modeling on iOS and maybe Android. Perhaps the situation with Xamarin has changed in the last year, or maybe I just don't understand much about building apps using it.

Comment: I found a reference to Smith's Algorithm (1962), and I will see how it works. Smith's paper does not seem to be available, but I found his formula references here http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/ComplexDivSPIE.pdf

Comment: The Smith algorithm is working, so I have a backup plan if I can't use System.Numerics.Complex with Xamarin. Thanks Peter Duniho.